# Get array of object property names from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm looking for something similar to this:

```
const object1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object1));
// expected output: Array ["a", "b", "c"]
```

However in my example I have:

```
const objectArray1 = [
  { a: 112, b: 322, c: 233 },
  { a: 611, b: 232, c: 331 },
  { a: 132, b: 232, c: 342 }
];
```

What's the most efficient way of getting the `["a", "b", "c"]` from this?

Also, that'll probably never happen but if one of `objectArray1` objects has `d: 345` in it or a missing key/value pair, that needs to be handled.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Map all entries of `objectArray1` to the object's keys using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), to get a flat array of all keys in all objects.
Then pass it through a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to extract the unique values. The `Set` can be converted back to an array using the `...` [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const objectArray1 = [
  { a: 112, b: 322, c: 233 },
  { a: 611, b: 232, c: 331 },
  { a: 132, b: 232, c: 342 },
  { a: 132, b: 232, c: 342, d: 532 }
];

const keys = [
  ...new Set(objectArray1.flatMap(Object.keys))
];

console.log(keys)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) in this case

```js
const object1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

const result = Object.keys(object1)

console.log(result)
```

If you have an array, you also can add `Set` to filter unique keys

```js
const objectArray1 = [
  { a: 112, b: 322, c: 233 },
  { a: 611, b: 232, c: 331 },
  { a: 132, b: 232, c: 342 }
];

const result = Array.from(new Set(objectArray1.flatMap((value) => Object.keys(value))))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)  with [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and then make a new unique array from it using [new Set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with spread operator [...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) .

```js
const objectArray1 = [
  { a: 112, c: 233 },
  { b: 232, c: 331 },
  { a: 132, b: 232, c: 342, d: 5 }
]


const uniqueKeys = (arr) => [...new Set(arr.flatMap(Object.keys))]

console.log(uniqueKeys(objectArray1))
//expected ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```